# jQuery - getElementById - how to change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, arduino, getelementbyid

I am using a web page as a server and the Arduino as a client. whenever any modes is active the arduino will send

```
 <LED>on</LED>
```

so the server based on this will change the status. I've change it to jQuery , the functionality is good but the text and color doesn't change

I was wondering that if someone could help me out to change the following code to jQuery?.. I've tried many things such as: `$('id').text('Ok');` but not working for me.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Code is:

```
if (this.responseXML.getElementsByTagName('LED')[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue === "on") {
    document.getElementById("evening").style.color = "#009933";
    document.getElementById("evening").innerHTML = "Evening Mode is ON";

    evening_state = 1;
} else {
    document.getElementById("evening").style.color = "#FF0000";
    document.getElementById("evening").innerHTML = "Evening Mode is OFF";

    evening_state = 0;
}
```

Comment: is this an ajax callback

Comment: Try `var $evening = $('#evening');
if ($(this.responseXML).find('LED:eq(1)').children().text() === "on") {
    $evening.css('color', '#009933').html('Evening Mode is ON');

    evening_state = 1;
} else {
    $evening.css('color', '#FF0000').html('Evening Mode is OFF');

    evening_state = 0;
}`

Comment: yes its ajax , I am using a web page a server and the Arduino as the client. whenever any modes is active the arduino will send <LED>on</LED>, so the server based on this will change the status. I've change it to jQuery , the functionality is good but the text and color doesn't change

Comment: the code doesn't work, should i consider changing the form of inputs from the arduino?

Comment: can you share the xml structure

Comment: arduino side code is : cl.print("<?xml version = \"1.0\" ?>"); cl.print("<LED>");
    if (LED_state[0]) {
        cl.print("on");
        
    }
    else {
        cl.print("off");
    }
    cl.println("</LED>");   and the server side is what i shared above .. I am new to stack sorry for the bad shape of my comments.

Comment: can you share the ajax request as well

Comment: till then try `var $evening = $('#evening');
if ($.trim($(this.responseXML).text()) === "on") {
 $evening.css('color', '#009933').html('Evening Mode is ON');
 evening_state = 1;
} else {
 $evening.css('color', '#FF0000').html('Evening Mode is OFF');
 evening_state = 0;
}`

Comment: request.open("GET", "http://10.1.7.5/ajax_inputs" + strLED1  + nocache, true);
   
request.send(null);

Comment: still not working  the problem is not related to the requests , cuz the functionality is OK and by clicking any button i could get the output, need to find a way to change the properties, thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$.ajax({
    url: '10.1.7.5/ajax_inputs' + strLED1 + nocache,
    dataType: 'xml'
}).done(function ($xml) {
    var $evening = $('#evening');

    alert($evening.length);
    alert($xml.text());
    if ($.trim($xml.text()) === "on") {
        $evening.css('color', '#009933').html('Evening Mode is ON');
        evening_state = 1;
    } else {
        $evening.css('color', '#FF0000').html('Evening Mode is OFF');
        evening_state = 0;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks alot .. i could manage it by using this parts of the code: var $evening = $('#evening');
        $evening.css('color', '#009933').html('Center Lamp is ON');

Answer (score 1):

**edit**

> whenever any modes is active the arduino will send
>
> `<LED>on</LED>`

I've updated my code example based on your updated question info.

---

While I'm not sure what your entire code base looks like. This should get you started.

<kbd>**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nQX6p/2/)**</kbd>

**JS**

```
$(function(){

    //Helper to fake an AJAX response. Not needed in your code. (from https://github.com/appendto/jquery-mockjax)
    $.mockjax({
      url: '/resource',
      responseTime: 100,
      responseXML: '<LED>on</LED>'
    });

    //Reference to your message element
    var evening = $('#evening'); 

    //jQuery ajax call
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '/resource', //URL to your ajax API
        dataType: 'xml'
    }).done(function(data){

        //Convert the returned document object to a jQuery object
        var ele = $(data); 
        if(ele.text() === 'on'){
            evening.css({'color': "#009933"}).text("Evening Mode is ON");
        }else{
            evening.css({'color': "#FF0000"}).text("Evening Mode is OFF");             
        }

    }); 

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id='evening'></div>
```

Comment: For parsing XML, better use `$.parseXML`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/.

Comment: @FelixKling - After a [quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/Mqa3S/1/), it appears that setting `dataType:'xml'` performs the same function as manually calling `$.parseXML` on a string value. In the above example, `data` is already a Document object when it's passed to the `done` function.

Comment: I've tried this one too , still doesn't working , I am using the code for arduino, the AJAX form works well , when i change the UI using JQ , the text and colors doesn't change. any idea? thanks a lot

Comment: Not sure I understand the context completely. I've never used an Arduino board so I'm not sure how accurately my answer relates to your problem space.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help, but still not working. my communication is working but changing the properties doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#id').text('xxx');
$('#id').html('xxx');
```

Comment: thanks for your response , I've tried this but still not working